# Parsing fractions

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing

My current goal is to parse fractions and create improper fractions.
For example:

1_1/3 + 5/3

should come into the console as

4/3 + 5/3

Could someone tell me am I going in the right direction and what should I be focusing on?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FracCalc {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to FracCalc");
            System.out.println("Type expressions with fractions, and I will evaluate them.");

        boolean isTrue = true;
        String in = "";
        while(isTrue) {
            in = input.nextLine();
            if (in.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for running FracCalc!");
                isTrue = false;
            }else{
                System.out.println("You asked me to compute" + in);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void parse(String in){
            int underscore = in.indexOf("_");
            int slash = in.lastIndexOf("/");

            String wholenumber = in.substring(0, underscore);
            String numerator = in.substring(underscore + 1,slash);
            String denominator = in.substring(slash + 1);

            if (underscore<0 & slash<0) {
                in = wholenumber;
            } else if (underscore<0 & slash>0) {
                in = in;
            } else if (underscore>0 & slash>0) {

            } else if (underscore>0 & slash<0) {
                in = "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say you `.split("_")` that string and automagically have both sides in a single step.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: we haven't learned about .split("_") I'm having problems with figuring out what to do for the } else if (underscore>0 & slash>0) { and also in the System.out.println("You asked me to compute" + in) I tried to replace in with parse but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're definitely on the right track although I'd consider a bit of a different approach to your parsing.

I would parse the string character by character. Iterate through the string and if your current character is a number, append it to a StringBuffer called "currentNumber" or something. If your current character is not a number you need to decide what to do. If it's an underscore, you know that the value in your currentNumber variable is the whole number part. You could then store that in a separate variable and clear your currentNumber buffer. If your current character is a slash character, you'd know that the value in currentNumber is the numerator of your fraction. If the current character is a space character you can probably just ignore it. If it is a '+' or '-', you'll know that what you have in your currentNumber variable is your fraction denominator. You should then also store the symbol in a separate variable as your "operator". There are numerous ways you could implement this. For example you could have logic that said: "if I have a valid value in my numerator and not in my denominator and the character I'm currently looking at is not a valid numeric character, then I have appended all the digits in my denominator to the currentNumber variable and it should therefore now contain my denominator. So put the value in currentNumber into my denominator variable and move on to the next character".

I hope I haven't lost you completely here... but of course this may be a bit too advanced for what you need to do. For example, you didn't specify the format of the input string, will it always be in the exact same format as you mentioned or can it look different? Can the whole number part have two digits or can it be skipped alltogether?

The method I described above is called a finite state machine and if you haven't learnt about them yet your teacher should probably be impressed if you handed in an assignment using this technique. There is a lot of reading material on FSM so Google is your friend.

But just to be clear. Your solution looks like it would work too, it just probably won't be as "dynamic".

Comment: Well, judging from your comment above, I'd say you probably haven't learnt about FSM and the above approach will most likely be a bit too much for you to tackle for now. But it's still something worth thinking about... and read up a bit on FSM. It'll be worth it.